# How to disable Auto-Mute Mode?

Tags: linux, alsa

In alsamixer, there is an option called "Auto-Mute Mode", and it's enabled by default.

But now I want to disable it. I've tried different keys but failed.

Any idea? 0_0

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Press right arrow to get to "auto-mute mode", then up or down arrow to change it, then Escape to exit.

You can make this automatic on boot by executing (perhaps in `/etc/rc.local`):

```
/usr/bin/amixer -c 0 sset "Auto-Mute Mode" Disabled
```

Comment: @Sam And would you have any idea on how to make this change permanent? Every time I restart my pc it gets reset.

Comment: try google: alsa save mixer settings

Comment: I would like to disable auto mute mode, but I don't have it, and `amixer -c 0 contents` doesn't show anything to that effect, and `amixer -c 0 sset "Auto-Mute Mode" Disabled` returns "Unable to find simple control 'Auto-Mute Mode',0". When I plug in my headphones, the speakers stop playing, though. Any ideas how I can change the setting?

Comment: @LimitedAtonement I don't know. Perhaps your sound device isn't fully supported by Linux kernel drivers, or perhaps the "auto mute" is done in hardware and can't be overridden in software.

Comment: @LimitedAtonement ^ for future reference: it could also mean that you have multiple sound devices (e.g. HDMI) and you may want to explore say `-c 1` and so on

Comment: @RiccardoM. Good catch. That was not the case in this particular instance.

Comment: I also had to set the `alsamixer` `Mic Mute-LED Mode` to `Follow Mute` for this work for me.

Answer (score 9):

Late answer.

I had the same problem, including **@limited-atonement** one.

To resume:

```
root@darkstar:~# amixer | grep -i mute
Simple mixer control 'Auto-Mute Mode',0
root@darkstar:~# amixer -c 0 sset 'Auto-Mute Mode' Disabled
amixer: Unable to find simple control 'Auto-Mute Mode',0
```

I solved it by running `alsamixer`, then:

- <kbd>F5</kbd> (show all controls)
- use arrows <kbd>→</kbd> to move until hitting the `<Auto-Mute>` control, which show as **Enabled**
- use the minus <kbd>-</kbd> key to switch it to **Disabled**
- hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit
- run `alsactl store` as root to save

Hope this help.

Answer (score 3):

Building on [Sam's answer](https://superuser.com/a/445761/734751), here is a script that toggles the status of Auto-Mute Mode:

```
# toggle status of Auto-Mute
if amixer -c 0 sget 'Auto-Mute Mode' | grep --quiet -F "Item0: 'Enabled"
then
    amixer -c 0 sset 'Auto-Mute Mode' Disabled
else
    amixer -c 0 sset 'Auto-Mute Mode' Enabled
fi
```

I'm using this so I can easily mute or un-mute my speakers without unplugging my headphones.

Edit: one-liner

`amixer -c 0 sget 'Auto-Mute Mode' | fgrep -q "Item0: 'E" && _M=Disabled || _M=Enabled; amixer -c 0 sset 'Auto-Mute Mode' $_M`